# Twig template in symfony2: Keep the position:fixed for multiple blocks

Tags: html, css, symfony, twig

I have a twig template in my symfony2 project and in there I have 4 blocks.

The block one is usualy a huge list of items, so the user has to scroll down on the page to see everything.

The problem is that the blocks 2, 3 and 4 and small in which concerns their height.

So, in order to have something "nice", I have to ideas:

1. Make the blocks 2, 3 and 4 to be always fixed, so when the user scrolls dow, the page will go down to se the block 1, but the content of the other blocks will allways be on the screen.

   For that, I know how to use CSS:

   ```
   position:fixed
   ```

   But I don't know how to use position:fixed for all the 4 blocks at once. I tryed to create an extra parent block but it does't work.
2. Fix the size of the block 1 and only scroll inside of the block 1, not on entire page. How can I do that? If I set with CSS:

   ```
   height: 100px
   ```

   Nothing hapens.

Thank you very much.

EDIT: Here is what I have tryed for the moment:

```
{% block global %}
    <div style="position:fixed ">
        {% block one %}
            ...
        {% endblock %}

        {% block two %}
            ...
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What HTML element do you call block?

Comment: @cheesemacfly, there are blocks in twig, it is not an html element. See: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/block.html

Comment: Yes but to get what you want you have to put those blocks inside HTML elements. For example `<div>`.

Comment: I tryed that but it seems that it is not working. I will try again and let you know in a couple of minutes

Comment: So, the problem is taht in twig, a template who is extending another one cant conain some body elements except in blocks. So in order to add an html element like div, I have to create a new block which will contain the other blocks, and this is not working because I am loosing the main structure.

Comment: Or you could use something like `{% block myblock %}<div>...</div>{% endblock %}`? Can you post what you have done so far?

Comment: @cheesemacfly, that's what I did, I created a block witho only a div and inside of the div I have 3 blocks. I wil paste some code in a minute

Comment: What if you create one `block` for your content that you need to scroll, and a second one containing all your other blocks and having the `position:fixed` properties?

Comment: Hi, this can't be done because i need to scrole more than one block.

Comment: So you want to keep block 2, 3 and 4 on top of your page and have block 1 below and being able to scroll through it?

Comment: Yes, it's almoas that. The block 1 should be on the left side of the page and I should be able to scroll through it. The other blocks, 2, 3 and 4 should be always displayed on the middle and right side of the page.